# Position of sidebar contents in relation to rest of page

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

On this page of my website: http://www.herefordequestrian.co.uk/ask-the-expert/
the right hand sidebar is not positioned top right of the page as it should be (and as it is on other pages). 
How do I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your #container 789px wide or less.

Comment: But on other pages isn't the container 1000px and causing no problem to the sidebar, or am I looking at the wrong container? Thanks by the way! I really appreciate everyones helpfulness on this website

Comment: Hey there- it's because on the other pages, your #sidebar is WITHIN your #container but on "ask-the-expert/" your #sidebar is OUTSIDE of your #container. Let me know if that does the trick...

Comment: That's weird because it was ok. What would've changed it? Also, sorry to be a novice, but how do I change it?

Comment: Hey there- wouldn't totally know without seeing your template, but if it's Wordpress, it's possible that get_sidebar(); is pasted at the wrong place. Look at the page template for "Ask the Expert" and compare the bottom of it to something like "page.php" or "index.php". Make sure that it is before the last closing </div> tag of id="container" and not after it. Hope that helps. If you want, paste the "Ask the Excerpt" template code here for me to see...